# Hide menu and redirect when clicking on react-router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

For the menu of my site I am using links. When clicked on menu hamburger icon a hover over menu appears which is a checkbox. Now I want to hide the menu after i click a Link  and go to another page. But the menu doesnt close, the page behind the menu changes which is good. I setup a function which changes the checkbox state to false but it doesn't hide the menu when a Link is clicked.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    hamburger: false
  };
  this.turnOff= this.turnOff.bind(this);
}

turnOff = (e) => {
    this.setState({hamburger:false});
}
```

in render()  i have:

```
<input name="hamburger" type="checkbox" id="menuToggle" onChange={this.handleChange} checked={this.state.hamburger} className="menu-toggle-input"></input>
<Link to="/about" onClick={this.turnOff}>About</Link>
```

When i click on link it loads the page on the background but the menu does not close and i get an error in console:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is this,

```
<Link to="/about" onClick={this.turnOff}>About</Link>
```

When you click on `Link`, it will not wait till any associated click handler executes, in your case `onClick={this.turnOff}`. It will directly navigates to component with path `/about` and your component `unmounts`. After component `unmounts`, your `turnOff` function tries to change state which is not possible.

Instead of `Link` you can have simple `button` (styled as link),

```
<button onClick={this.turnOff}>About</button>
```

You can make use of [`Redirect`](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a) from `react-router-dom` package, in [callback](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) of setState.

Your function should be,

```
turnOff = (e) => {
    this.setState({hamburger:false}, () => <Redirect to="/about" />);
}
```

**Update**

You can make use of `history` object,

```
turnOff = (e) => {
    this.setState({hamburger:false}, () => this.props.history.push('/about'));
}
```

You need to import `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` and wrap your component with same.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


export default withRouter(Your_Component_name)
```

Comment: I tried this it hides the menu due to the setting of the state to false but doesn't load the new page

Comment: have you added `Redirect `,

Comment: yes i did but no errors nothing and it stays on the same page